# How to calculate precision and recall for two nested arrays

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, precision, precision-recall

I have two arrays like:

```
correct = [['*','*'],['*','PER','*','GPE','ORG'],['GPE','*','*','*','ORG']]
predicted = [['PER','*'],['*','ORG','*','GPE','ORG'],['PER','*','*','*','MISC']]
```

Length of correct and predicted is same(10K+) also the length of each positional element in two arrays have the same length.
I want to calculate the precision, recall, and f1 score for such two arrays using python.
I Have following 6 classes:
  'PER','ORG','MISC','LOC','*','GPE'

want to calculate precision and recall for 5 of the classes (Except '*') also to find f1 score.
what can be the efficient way to perform this using python?

Comment: Why a list of lists, with the inner lists having different lengths (2 & 5)??

Comment: these are the results of an NER model. The lists inside the list are representing the sentences so in the above case 1st sentence has 2 words then next is having 5 and so the length of inside lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to flatten your lists as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/making-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists-in-python), and then use `classification_report` from scikit-learn:

```
correct = [['*','*'],['*','PER','*','GPE','ORG'],['GPE','*','*','*','ORG']]
predicted = [['PER','*'],['*','ORG','*','GPE','ORG'],['PER','*','*','*','MISC']]
target_names = ['PER','ORG','MISC','LOC','GPE'] # leave out '*'

correct_flat = [item for sublist in correct for item in sublist]
predicted_flat = [item for sublist in predicted for item in sublist]

from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
print(classification_report(correct_flat, predicted_flat, target_names=target_names))
```

Result:

```
             precision    recall  f1-score   support

        PER       1.00      0.86      0.92         7
        ORG       1.00      0.50      0.67         2
       MISC       0.00      0.00      0.00         0
        LOC       0.50      0.50      0.50         2
        GPE       0.00      0.00      0.00         1

avg / total       0.83      0.67      0.73        12
```

In this particular example, you will also get a warning:

```
UndefinedMetricWarning: Recall and F-score are ill-defined and being set to 0.0 in labels with no true samples.
```

which is due to `'MISC'` not being present in the true labels here (`correct`), but arguably this should not happen in your real data.

Comment: Yes, this worked, Thank you. Hope you will undo your devote to this question.